# Is there a way to paste a clipboard text into the actual Android native app?

Tags: android, clipboard, android-10.0

For a showcase we want to write an Android native app that runs in the background and creates an clipboard item (simple text). After a while, e.g. 3 seconds, the service should paste/drop this text into the actual input field of the actual active app (e.g. URL field in Google Chrome).
Is there a way to do this, especially on Android >= 10?

Comment: Apps generally cannot force input into other apps, for security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, that seems to be obvious. But we have a Honeywell Tablet with a barcode scanner who pasted the scan result into any focused EditView field - until Android 9. But with Android 10 this doesn't work anymore. For me it is not clear, if I have to change something in my app to 'reenable' pasting. Or if this is a bug in Honeywell's Android 10 version.

Comment: Did you happen to change which soft keyboard implementation you use? Perhaps the barcode scanner was integrated into the former one. Otherwise, this feels like a Honeywell issue. You could test whether it is tied to your app perhaps by testing fields in other apps (e.g., Settings).

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you explain this in detail? We don't have any specific soft keyboard implementation. This is a simple SearchView with number input type. The scanner is a black box for us - Honeywell doesn't provide any information about this.

Comment: "Can you explain this in detail?" -- in the Settings app, you should be able to choose your input method editor (soft keyboard). See if there is now more than one, and if so, see if your barcode scanner works with the other one.